# Using SDK on an Android device?

Tags: android, sdk

OK, possible stupid question - apologies - but can you install the SDK and Eclipse on an Android device (I'm thinking a tablet)?

I realise it will be trickier to use without a proper keyboard etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this on an android tablet.  Although there is an app on the market called "Java Code Viewer" by Ahyane that will allow you to open java code, view and edit it on an android device.  The app does read syntax, however sdk and library support are not part of the apps current functions.

I use it occasionally to tinker with some source code while I am thinking about it and then run it on eclipse when I am home.